# how do i use querySelector the right way

Tags: javascript, navbar, selectors-api, queryselector

I want the navbar `<ul>` to disappear when I click it. With `querySelectorAll()` I selected all `<li>`s in the navbar. Then I added a click event listener to it. So when I click it, it should toggle the class of the navbar `<ul>` to "active" and then disappear.

It works with the toggle button but not with the `<li>`s.

```html
<i id="togglebtn" class="fas fa-bars"></i>

<nav class="navbar">
    <div class="brand-title">brandName</div>
    <div class="navbar-links">
        <ul id="ul">
            <li class="jsscrolltrigger"><a href="#logo">Start</a></li>
            <li class="jsscrolltrigger"><a href="#Galerie">Galerie</a></li>
            <li class="jsscrolltrigger"><a href="#Adresse">Anfahrt</a></li>
            <li class="jsscrolltrigger"><a href="#Speisekarte">Speisekarte</>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var togglebtn = document.getElementById("togglebtn");
    togglebtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
        ul.classList.toggle("active");
    });
    // this following part doesnt work //
    // i want the ul(navbar) to disappear when i click it //

    var a = document.querySelectorAll(".jsscrolltrigger");
    var ul = document.getElementById("ul");
    a.addEventListener("click", function () {
        ul.classList.toggle("active");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do querySelectorAll and getElementsBy\* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return)

Answer (score 0):

`querySelectorAll` returns a `NodeList`. You have to iterate the list and add the event listener to every node.

For example:

```js
var togglebtn = document.getElementById("togglebtn");
togglebtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  ul.classList.toggle("active");
});


var nodeList = document.querySelectorAll(".jsscrolltrigger");
var ul = document.getElementById("ul");

nodeList.forEach(node => {
  node.addEventListener("click", function() {
    ul.classList.toggle("active");
  });
})
```

```html
<i id="togglebtn" class="fas fa-bars"></i>
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="brand-title">brandName</div>
  <div class="navbar-links">
    <ul id="ul">
      <li class="jsscrolltrigger"><a href="#logo">Start</a></li>
      <li class="jsscrolltrigger"><a href="#Galerie">Galerie</a></li>
      <li class="jsscrolltrigger"><a href="#Adresse">Anfahrt</a></li>
      <li class="jsscrolltrigger"><a href="#Speisekarte">Speisekarte</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use [`Document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) It doesn't return a single element. It return a `NodeList` on which you can call `forEach` to loop through all of the item.

```js
let a = document.querySelectorAll('.jsscrolltrigger');

let ul = document.getElementById("ul");

a.forEach(function(element) {
  element.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    ul.classList.toggle("active");
  });
});
```

```css
.active {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
    <div class="brand-title">brandName</div>
    <div class="navbar-links">
        <ul id="ul">
            <li class="jsscrolltrigger"><a href="#logo">Start</a></li>
            <li class="jsscrolltrigger"><a href="#Galerie">Galerie</a></li>
            <li class="jsscrolltrigger"><a href="#Adresse">Anfahrt</a></li>
            <li class="jsscrolltrigger"><a href="#Speisekarte">Speisekarte</>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

If you don't want to use `forEach` to perform the loop you can force the `NodeList` to be consider as an `Array` by passing it to the [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) method which allows you to perform any array operation on selected elements

```
Array.from(a).map(function(){ /*...*/ });
Array.from(a).filter(function(){ /*...*/ });
```